# Magento 2 Data Migration Tool ignore unknown documents

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am going to migrate data with the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool. Because the Magento 1 installation I want to migrate has lots of custom tables that come from extensions, I get tons of errors when migrating data. I would be fine to only migrate the standard magento tables.

Do I have to add an ignore statement to the map.xml file for **every** document I want to ignore? This is a lot of work for me, so my question is, is there any possibility to tell the migration tool to just ignore unknown documents?

My workaround would be to figure out some handy search/replace pattern to generate the xml from the error message I get from the data migration tool.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You will have to add ignore for every table to avoid all errors in migration and for successful migration.

You can add ignore for all tables with specific extension. ie for ignoring all catalog tables you only need to add one statement:

```
<ignore><document>catalog_*</document></ignore>
```

This will ignore all tables starting with some specific extension.

I believe user must have answer for this but sharing this will help community members.